# Linkedin WhereHows - Docker Backend not able to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, web, playframework, connection

When I try to connect WhereHows backend to MySQL DB in Docker environment I am getting following error message (I checked IP, Username and Password and all 3 are good):

```
1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [wherehows]]
```

At the same time, WhereHows web is connecting without any problem.

Docker version is `17.12.0-ce` and I am using following images:

- wherehows/backend
- wherehows/web
- wherehows/mysql

#### This is my config file - /backend-service/conf/application.conf

```
# connection to wherehows mysql database
db.wherehows.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.wherehows.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/wherehows?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false"
db.wherehows.username="wherehows"
db.wherehows.password="wherehows"
```